# Preserving Facebook likes and comments while performing a SEO friendly migration

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, redirect

Good day!

I just moved to a Linux server and thanks to .htaccess I am about to migrate my old page:
www.site.com/oldfolder/oldfile.php
to
www.site.com/SEO-friendly-folder/newfile ->points to folder oldfolder/newfile.php

I would like to perform the migration in a SEO friendly way but at the same time I want to preserve Facebook likes and comments linked to oldfile.php

Googling a bit I found the following suggestions:

1. The new page should contain the old og:url from oldfile
2. I should insert a 301 redirect in oldfile so to tell to Search Engines it's a permanent move
3. I should make oldfolder unaccessible via web (still this should not generate a redirect loop)

Before performing this important change I wanted to know if there are further steps that could be taken into consideration, specifically:

a. If having a og:url that points to an old page is going to affect the Search Engine's ranking somehow.
 b. Best way to implement such a redirect (oldfolder should not be accessible but the redirect from newfolder should work)

I hope it's not a too broad question, the point is that the different aspects are merged together.

Comment: Most important, you need to keep your old URLs available to the FB scraper, so that it can read the OG meta data from them – and that means, if you redirect old to new, you need to exempt the FB scraper from that redirect.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually one of the suggested methods by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler#updating But I though about opting for the second one (using the old og:url) as in this way the new page will at least receive the new comments ("New likes at either location will aggregate in both places.").